# Jenkins slave running in ECS cluster start container slow

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ecs, jenkins-agent

I'm using Jenkins slave in AWS ECS cluster, everytime when I press build, slave container take 3mins to start, how can I speed up this?

Comment: I am not having a 3 minute startup but more like 30 seconds, which I think is too slow. I want to actually just have one running, pre-warmed.

Comment: May I know which Jenkins and ecs plugin version are you using? I still cannot solve the problem

Comment: Sure, Jenkins ver. 2.138.3 + https://plugins.jenkins.io/amazon-ecs  1.18.

Comment: Hi @ElijahLynn, do you set a fix vaule for Soft memory reservation, Hard memory, CPU unit in ECS cloud confiugration ?

Comment: Soft Memory = 0, Hard Memory 2048, CPU Units = 1000. 

All settings https://imgur.com/a/2Q0CzZM

Comment: How fast do your containers start with regular `docker-compose`?

Comment: Set value for Hard Memory made a magic, the container start up around 10s. But I have another problem, some build job seen require memory more than Hard Memory reservation. Even I set 4096 for Hard Memory, I still got error: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called

Comment: Do you get any cluster logs on the ECS side?

Comment: I see some scary log messages in Jenkins when the ECS side terminates, but usually everything is fine on ECS side and it is just that the Jenkins log message doesn't know how to handle that termination and throws an exception or something along those lines. I haven't actually looked that closely at them. If it worked you would see something under the "stopped" section of the tasks. Then expand that task and look at the logs. If you don't see a task under "stopped" then it never got that far.

Comment: Good to hear you get 10 seconds, I am guessing our containers are just way too bloated. Time to "FROM alpine", lol.